# Readonly DependencyProperty does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

My existing C#/WPF project is not working now after installing visual studio 2008. But previously it was working fine in **visual studio 2008**.

I'm getting the following error on XAML

> The property 'DesignTimeHelper.DesignTimeData' does not exist in XML
>   namespace 'clr-namespace:Monitor.Controls'. Line 13 Position 5.

Please find the attached xaml and cs file

```
    <UserControl
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
        xmlns:crl="clr-namespace:Monitor.Controls"
        xmlns:dat="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:UIControls;assembly=UIControls"
        crl:DesignTimeHelper.DesignTimeData="{x:Type svm:SampleAlertsTabViewModel}"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">

        ...
    </UserControl>
```

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace Monitor.Controls
    {
        public static class DesignTimeHelper
        {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DesignTimeDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DesignTimeData", typeof(Type), typeof(DesignTimeHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDesignTimeDataChanged)));

        public static Type GetDesignTimeData(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Type)obj.GetValue(DesignTimeDataProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDesignTimeData(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DesignTimeDataProperty, value);
        }


        private static void OnDesignTimeDataChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var isOnDesignMode = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject());
            if (isOnDesignMode)
            {
            var element = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("element must not be null and must be an UIElement.");

            var designTimeDataType = e.NewValue as Type;
            if (designTimeDataType == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("designTimeDataType must not be null.");

            element.DataContext = Activator.CreateInstance(designTimeDataType);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

why DependencyProperty is not working now ? it requires any other dependency?

please share your ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Which VS it worked in, and in which it doesn't? Is it in the same assembly? Show your `xmlns` declaration.

Comment: Did you also declare the static getter and setter methods, as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx#custom)? They are essential.

Comment: Yes.included the getter and setter methods. please check..